# Return a linq reasult as 2D array?

Tags: c#, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am reading config files by using Linq that returns an array.

There are to Linq query in single function, one is return port number, and another one project names. That function returns both in 2D array(OR anything).

```
  public string[][] GetProjectsPorts(string cruiseControlPath)
    {
          var projectNames = (from item in xdoc.Elements("project")
                                select item.Attribute("name").Value).ToArray();


          var portNumber = (from item in xdoc.Elements("system.runtime.remoting").
                                  Elements("application").Elements("channels").Elements("channel")
                              select item.Attribute("port").Value).ToArray();

        return ??
    }
```

problem is, How I put both array into a single 2D array.....

Another option is to return it as a dictionary, but it could have multiple same project names.

Thanx for suggestions.

Comment: By the way, what you have here is an array of arrays (or jagged array). 2D array would be `string[,]`. It's important to know the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:-

```
 return new string[][] { projectNames, portNumber};
```

Comment: yes you are right!!!I foget to mention, there are many project for one port number. So my output like projectname with port number

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest encapsulating the pair of { Project, Port } in a separate data type, and return an array (or list) of that type. Aside from anything else, that way the port number can be a number rather than a string :)

If you're using .NET 4 you could use a `Tuple<string, int>` but if this is going to be used quite a lot you should consider creating your own type for the sake of readability (the properties "Project" and "Port" are considerably clearer than "Item1" and "Item2").

Comment: Oh!! how is the Idea to reate a class that store the information, because I am having multiple project with one port number